# How to check and control background processes/task in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to monitor (and kill) Thunderbird processes/tasks like how one would do that in [Chrome's task manager](https://www.howtogeek.com/437681/how-to-use-chromes-built-in-task-manager/) (pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)?

My experience is very choppy, and would prefer to do any indexing, compacting, etc. jobs when I'm not actively replying to emails or using another machine entirely.

<sup>At least, until I figure out how to migrate to Mutt.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no task manager.

Identifying the cause of Thunderbird performance issues is a process of peeling the onion. It's in need of an update, but https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Testing:Memory_Usage_Problems is a good starting point.